# Rename multiple files removing date VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, file-rename

I new on VB.NET and I'am trying to rename multiple files, removing the dates, using VB.NET:

TEST_FILE_20230624.csv to be like TEST_FILE.csv

The dates must be dynamic, since I'll get files from a folder that will have the date of the export (date will change according to the date of the export).

Is it possible to do this?

Thanks a lot.

RM

Comment: What should happen if there is a naming clash? E.g. if the directory contained "TEST_FILE_20230624.csv" and "TEST_FILE.csv", should the former be deleted?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the ChatGPT answer posted by @lazanhvgTennis and it works with a bit of tweaking (change method parameter to `filePath` to avoid clash with `IO.Path`):

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Sub RenameFiles(filePath As String)
    ' Fetch all .csv files in the specified directory
    Dim files As String() = Directory.GetFiles(filePath, "*.csv")

    ' Loop through all the files
    For Each file In files
      ' Grab the file info
      Dim fileInfo As New FileInfo(file)

      ' Grab the base name of the file (without extension)
      Dim baseName As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileInfo.Name)

      ' Use Regex to remove the date pattern
      Dim noDateName As String = Regex.Replace(baseName, "_\d{8}$", "")

      ' Get the new file name with the original extension
      Dim newFileName As String = $"{noDateName}{fileInfo.Extension}"

      ' Get the full path for the new file name
      Dim newFilePath As String = Path.Combine(fileInfo.DirectoryName, newFileName)

      ' Rename the file by moving it to the new name
      fileInfo.MoveTo(newFilePath)
    Next
End Sub
```

I guess we'll all be replaced with robots soon.

Comment: The only reason you need to qualify the `Path` class is because the name clashes with the `path` parameter. I would tend to use `filePath` for the parameter, so there would be no name clash.